# Как перевести данные из xml-файла в базу данных Access и обратно?

Tags: c#

```
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=C://Evgeny/Desktop/bd.mdb";
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM FIZ",con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Customers");
    ds.WriteXml("C://Users/Evgeny/Desktop/bd.xml");
```

Прочитал данный пример по переводу из БД в xml, но что-то не работает, заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: `что-то не работает` как это понимать?

Comment: `ds.ReadXml(...)`